# Indent dialogue to make text look less blocky

Tags: creative-writing, style, dialogue

I am writing a story but I am trying to indent the dialog because right now it looks like a chunk of text.

My text is

> Then a figure under the box moved behind Professor to which John yelled “Professor! Watch out!” But due to his old age, he didn't hear him...

Would I indent it like

> Then a figure under the box moved behind Professor to which John yelled
>    “Professor! Watch out!”
>   But due to his old age, he didn't hear him...

I tried researching but don't exactly get how to implement it into my story, also how else can I indent my story to make it look less like a big blob of text without having to introduce a new paragraph

Comment: Hi _Dan_, what software are you using? In most word processors, simply pressing "enter/return" will create a new line and push the text after it downwards. Have you tried that?

Comment: You seem to want to have a paragraph without extra spacing. Easily doable in MS Word (Paragraph/Spacing/After), should be doable in all other text processors.

Comment: I did the indenting for you. But don't. Non-standard formatting just calls attention to your non-standard formatting. It does not make you story any more inviting or any easier to read. Concentrate on telling a good story and use the same formatting as everyone else.

Comment: @MarkBaker So I should keep it as a blob of text?

Comment: @Dan I would. Breaking it up does not seem to add to readability, which is really the only standard that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your paragraph is a gray wall of text, break it up where it makes sense. You aren't required to break it *only* on dialogue. And trim your narration too:

> A figure under the box moved behind Professor. John yelled “Professor! Watch out!” Professor didn't hear him.
>
> John had no choice. He leapt forward and tackled the shadow looming behind his mentor. They crashed to the ground in a tangle of flailing limbs. He couldn't get his bearings enough for a proper attack, and punched and kicked at the mystery figure in desperation.
>
> From the other side of the room, a woman shouted "STOP!" Professor cried out something in response, but John couldn't make it out.

Each paragraph is a small *beat*, or a moment or thought. You can have longer beats and shorter beats. Vary them to help your readability.

Comment: Thanks! I really like the idea of making each one a moment!

Answer (score 0):

Dialogue is just a normal paragraph and is indented as all other paragraphs are.

If you indent the first line of each paragraph in your text, indent dialogue too:

> John does and says a lot of things so that we have a paragraph with multiple lines. I'll just keep writing, until there are at least three lines. I hope you will forgive me for the nonsense I write here.
>      "What kind of nonsense are you writing here, Cloudchaser?" John asked me.
>      "I'm just filling the lines," I replied.

If you do not indent the first line in every paragraph, do not indent dialogue either:

> John does and says a lot of things so that we have a paragraph with multiple lines. I'll just keep writing, until there are at least three lines. I hope you will forgive me for the nonsense I write here.
>   "What kind of nonsense are you writing here, Cloudchaser?" John asked me.
>   "I'm just filling the lines," I replied.

---

In your example, the spoken words are part of another sentence and therefore **do not form their own paragraph**. You just forgot a colon:

> Then a figure under the box moved behind Professor to which John yelled: “Professor! Watch out!” But due to his old age, he didn't hear him...